# .NET 6 not recognizing database from Azure Data Studio

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, razor-pages, azure-data-studio

I am trying to connect to a database for my application in .NET 6. My connection string is as follows:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
        "Default": "Server=localhost;Database=Tim;User Id=SA;Password=*****;TrustServerCertificate=true"
}
```

It is defined in `appsettings.json`.

In Azure Data Studio, I have a database named `Tim` which I am trying to access:

[image]

But when I run my application I get the following error

> SqlException: Invalid object name 'Tim'.
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand+<>c.b__209_0(Task result)
> System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask<TAntecedentResult, TResult>.InnerInvoke()
> System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, object state)
> System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, object state)
> System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(ref Task currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)
> Dapper.SqlMapper.QueryAsync(IDbConnection cnn, Type effectiveType, CommandDefinition command) in SqlMapper.Async.cs
> DataLibrary.DB.SqlDb.LoadData<T, U>(string storedProcedure, U parameters, string connectionStringName)
> RPDemoApp.Pages.Orders.CreateModel.OnGet() in Create.cshtml.cs

- var food = await _foodData.GetFood();
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.ExecutorFactory+NonGenericTaskHandlerMethod.Execute(object receiver, object[] arguments)
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.InvokeHandlerMethodAsync()
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.InvokeNextPageFilterAsync()
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.Rethrow(PageHandlerExecutedContext context)
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)

What mistake am I making?

**EDIT**: here is my Service collector code

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton(new ConnectionStringData
{
    SqlConnectionName= "DefaultConnection"
});

builder.Services.AddSingleton<IDataAccess, SqlDb>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IFoodData, FoodData>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IOrderData, OrderData>();
```

Here is the `GetFood` method, it uses a stored procedure to get data from the database:

```
public Task<List<FoodModel>> GetFood()
{
    return _dataAccess.LoadData<FoodModel, dynamic>("dbo.spFood_All",
                                                            new { },
                                                            _connectionString.SqlConnectionName);
}
```

Comment: why you are using localhost ? is not the name of the azure database ?

Comment: I am using azure data studio locally, as I have macOS, I need to use that for SQL related stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your settings file change `Connection` to `DefaultConnection`, `Source` to `Data Source` and `Database` to `Initial Catalog` as follows:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=Tim;User Id=sa;Password=Password;TrustServerCertificate=true;"
  },
```

**UPDATE:**

The error is 100% related to the stored procedure code. The select is referencing a database instead of a table.

Please change the stored procedure select statement to use the table name.

You can also use `[DBNAME].[SCHEMA].[TABLENAME]` so something like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spFood_All] 
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT
        [ID], [Title], [Descrip], [Price] 
    FROM
        Tim.dbo.[TABLENAME]; 
END
```

Comment: I am still getting the same exact error.

Comment: can you paste here the code in ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) ?

Comment: also how GetFood method looks ?

Comment: I have edited the question, please take a look.

Comment: based on the exception trace the storeprocedure sp_foodall within GetFood calls should be referencing the database Tim, please confirm.

Comment: yes,sp_foodall is a store procedure within the database Tim.

Comment: and it is calling another object within the same DB correct ? such as table,view,function...whatever

Comment: Yes, ```GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spFood_All]
AS
BEGIN
    set nocount on;
    select [ID], [Title], [Descrip], [Price] from Tim;
END
GO
```

Comment: thanks for the sp details, please see the UPDATE section on the answer and mark it as a response if it helps. thanks !